# How to store and use the input given dynamically

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, java.util.scanner, dynamic-arrays

I'm working on a question where I need to store and use the data given by the user. The data given by the user is usually in the below format.

Input:

```
5
0
4 5 1 0
1 0
5 3 0
3 0
```

Let's say the user enters a value for 'N' where N>1 and N<500.
In the above example, N=5;
so now, there will be N lines available for the user to enter numbers between 1 and 100 again.
According to the above example, the next N (here N=5) lines contains numbers given randomly by the user. Each line can contain one number or more than 1 which are separated by the spaces. But the code should break after 5 lines are finished. The user should not be able to enter any more data after N lines.

My question is, how can i take the input from the user where there should be N lines and each line can store one or more than one value (<=100)(each value separated by spaces) and should end after the N lines are finished. 
I'm not able to come up with any solution. kindly help me on giving me some ideas on how can i go about with it. Thanks.

Comment: use a while loop with scanner.nextLine() which loops n times and then split the read value input.split() and loop through the splitarrary and store in List<Set<Integer>>

Comment: for syntax use http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/

Comment: i can use scanner.hasNext() but how can i make it run for n times ?

Comment: Scanner sc = new Scanner();

String s;

while(true)
{
System.out.println("Pleasde enter the input");
s = sc.nextLine
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for example

```
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
       String line = reader.nextLine();
       while (!line.equals("")) {
           // what ever you has to do
           System.out.println(line);
           line = reader.nextLine();
       }
   }
```

This code read lines until the user press enter and dont have an input

Comment: This `while (line != null && !line.equals(""))` makes me wonder if you really know how `Scanner` works. (Hint, it doesn't act like for example a `BufferedReader`)

Comment: You are right Tom with checking empty string must be enough, thanks.

Comment: *"checking empty string must be enough"* only if you're reading from `System.in` and this is luckily the case.